# WordPress opens link in same window despite target="_blank"

Tags: html, wordpress, hyperlink, target

On my page http://verein-iks.eu/dev/ I have a Facebook button on the top-right. If I click the button, I get forwarded to a Facebook page. However, the link is opened in the same window. I want it to be opened in a new window/tab. Hence, I use `target='_blank'` in the HTML code. Still, the link gets opened in the *same* window! Why?

When checking the source code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in Firefox and Chrome) of the page, you can see on line 166 that the target is indeed set to `target="_blank"`. Strangely, when I inspect the element (in Chrome via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>), the `target="_blank"` property seems to have disappeared.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have wp accessibility plugin activated in your wordpress installation there is a checkbox in wp accessibility settings, under **Miscellaneous Accessibility Settings** which called *Remove target attribute from links*. Uncheck it and everything will by fine :)

Comment: thanks! After handreading just about every function written for my new theme this was the solution. Not my code related. happy days +1 @john-gagiatsos

Answer (score 1):

In the footer of your DOM, there is a `<script>` that is removing the target attribute from all links...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(function( $ ) { 'use strict';

    $('a').removeAttr('target');    //This will remove the target attribute from all links on page load   

    $('input,a,select,textarea,button').removeAttr('tabindex');

}(jQuery));
//]]>
</script>
```

The reason you see the attribute when viewing the source is due to the fact that the source is what was received from the server. Inspect Element is a live view of what happens with the DOM, so it renders the result of the executed JS.

Comment: do you know why wordpress is doing this? do I lose something, if I get rid of this script?

Comment: Could be the theme, a plugin, hard to say. Something you will have to figure out honestly. As far as "losing" something is concerned, if you removed this script, any `<a>` tag that had `target="_blank"` would keep it. Hardly a loss in my opinion.

Comment: To be clear, Wordpress is not doing this. Your theme or a plugin you have installed is doing this...

Comment: thanks for the pointers. The plugin which is doing this is "WP Accessibility". Maybe for impaired people (who use screenreaders) it makes sense to not have such links.